# Matplotlib won't run on Windows 10 -- DLL fails to load

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have installed matplotlib on a Windows 10 machine using

`pip3 install matplotlib`

I get a message that it's using the wheel

`matplotlib-3.4.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl1`

When I type `import matplotlib` in a python 3.9 shell, I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from . import _api, cbook, docstring, rcsetup
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 26, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 82, in <module>
    from matplotlib import _api, cbook, scale
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\scale.py", line 18, in <module>
    from matplotlib.ticker import (
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 179, in <module>
    from matplotlib import transforms as mtransforms
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 46, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _path: The specified module could not be found.
```

I ran the installation under Windows Terminal, as an administrator.

How can I fix this?  I don't want to install anaconda or WinPython, if I can avoid it.  I just want matplotlib to work.

Comment: Coincidentally almost identical stack trace to [this question from 2 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66917895/9245853).

Comment: @BigBen I saw that, but unless I'm missing something the solutions require anaconda, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: I'm not seeing the Anaconda reference.

Comment: @BigBen Sorry.  I ignored the answer about downloading DLL's from YouTube, and followed the link on the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

> This issue is present again with matplotlib 3.3.2, 3.3.3 and 3.3.4. .
> matplotlib 3.3.0 3.3.1 work.

I found a solution by [mkunzBGC](https://github.com/mkunzBGC) on Github:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18292#issuecomment-792634734

The downgrade to matplotlib 3.3.1 worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. If you have already installed matplotlib, but the error still comes about. Then you have to download Microsoft C++ from their website. https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/Download/confirmation.aspx?id=48145

install Microsoft c++ then you can try again to run your code. it has worked for me like magic. I got the solution from a youtube video.

link here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DpwsvUkNAmg

Comment: This "worked" (although suggest simply googling: "microsoft c++ download") for me...felt like it was a last resort. I don't really care, but assuming I'm going to package my executables (via pipenv), this would cause a problem on the user's system (because they won't have the C libraries installed).