# Matplotlib import error: "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _path: The specific module could not be found"

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib

I installed Python3.10 (64x)(download installer from the official website) on the clear Windows 10 (x64).
Using `pip install <packetname>` I installed packages: numpy, scipy and matplotlib.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYYtH.png)

Numpy and scipy work properly, but matplotlib import falls with `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _path: The specific module could not be found`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0xMH.png)

It falls in the transforms.py on the command:
`from matplotlib._path import ( affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox, update_path_extents)`

I've tried reinstall matplotlib and install older versions - no result. Reviewing the forums with similar questions also wasn't successful.

Please, help me to get by this issue.

Comment: Maybe look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66919838/matplotlib-wont-run-on-windows-10-dll-fails-to-load

Comment: Yes, I saw this topic, but no advices helped. I revealed, that the problem disappears if I import pandas library before matplotlib.